# Fast calculation of v-disparity with OpenCV-Function calcHist

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

Based on a disparity matrix from a passive stereo-camera system i need to calculate a v-disparity representation for obstacle detection with OpenCV.

A working implementation is **not** the problem. The problem is to do it fast...

(One) Reference for v-Disparity: Labayrade, R. and Aubert, D. and Tarel, J.P. Real time obstacle detection in stereovision on non flat road geometry through v-disparity representation

The basic in short, to get the v-disparity (figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPvsg.png)), is to analyze the rows of the disparity-matrix (figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXYvf.png)) an represent the result as a histogram for each row over the disparity values. u-disparity (figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0qSt.png)) is the same on the columns of the disparity-matrix. (All figures are false-colored.)

I have implement the "same" in Python and C++. The speed in Python is acceptable but in C++ i get for the u- and v-disparity a time round about a half second (0.5 s).

*(1. edit: due to the separate time measurement, only the calculation of the u-histogram takes a big amount of time...)*

This leads me to following questions:

1. Is it possible to avoid the loops for the line-wise calculation of the histogram? Is there a "trick" to do it with one call of `calcHist`-Function from OpenCV? Perhaps with the dimensions?
2. Is it in C++ just bad-coded and the runtime-issue are not related to the loops used for calculation?

Thanks, all

---

Working implementation in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# THIS SOURCE-CODE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED. IN NO  EVENT WILL THE AUTHOR BE HELD LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES ARISING FROM
# THE USE OF THIS SOURCE-CODE. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

def draw_object(image, x, y, width=50, height=100):
    color = image[y, x]
    image[y-height:y, x-width//2:x+width//2] = color


IMAGE_HEIGHT = 600
IMAGE_WIDTH = 800

while True:

    max_disp = 200

    # create fake disparity
    image = np.zeros((IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH), np.uint8)

    for c in range(IMAGE_HEIGHT)[::-1]:
        image[c, ...] = int(float(c) / IMAGE_HEIGHT * max_disp)

    draw_object(image, 275, 175)
    draw_object(image, 300, 200)
    draw_object(image, 100, 350)

    # calculate v-disparity
    vhist_vis = np.zeros((IMAGE_HEIGHT, max_disp), np.float)
    for i in range(IMAGE_HEIGHT):
        vhist_vis[i, ...] = cv2.calcHist(images=[image[i, ...]], channels=[0], mask=None, histSize=[max_disp],
                                         ranges=[0, max_disp]).flatten() / float(IMAGE_HEIGHT)


    vhist_vis = np.array(vhist_vis * 255, np.uint8)
    vblack_mask = vhist_vis < 5
    vhist_vis = cv2.applyColorMap(vhist_vis, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
    vhist_vis[vblack_mask] = 0

    # calculate u-disparity
    uhist_vis = np.zeros((max_disp, IMAGE_WIDTH), np.float)
    for i in range(IMAGE_WIDTH):
        uhist_vis[..., i] = cv2.calcHist(images=[image[..., i]], channels=[0], mask=None, histSize=[max_disp],
                                         ranges=[0, max_disp]).flatten() / float(IMAGE_WIDTH)

    uhist_vis = np.array(uhist_vis * 255, np.uint8)
    ublack_mask = uhist_vis < 5
    uhist_vis = cv2.applyColorMap(uhist_vis, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
    uhist_vis[ublack_mask] = 0


    image = cv2.applyColorMap(image, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)


    cv2.imshow('image', image)

    cv2.imshow('vhist_vis', vhist_vis)
    cv2.imshow('uhist_vis', uhist_vis)

    cv2.imwrite('disparity_image.png', image)
    cv2.imwrite('v-disparity.png', vhist_vis)
    cv2.imwrite('u-disparity.png', uhist_vis)


    if chr(cv2.waitKey(0)&255) == 'q':
        break
```

---

Working implementation in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ctime>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace std;

void draw_object(cv::Mat image, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int width=50, unsigned int height=100)
{
    image(cv::Range(y-height, y), cv::Range(x-width/2, x+width/2)) = image.at<unsigned char>(y, x);
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 600;
    unsigned int IMAGE_WIDTH = 800;
    unsigned int MAX_DISP = 250;
    unsigned int CYCLE = 0;

    //setenv("QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM", "native", 1);


    // === PREPERATIONS ==
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, CV_8U);
    cv::Mat uhist = cv::Mat::zeros(IMAGE_HEIGHT, MAX_DISP, CV_32F);
    cv::Mat vhist = cv::Mat::zeros(MAX_DISP, IMAGE_WIDTH, CV_32F);

    cv::Mat tmpImageMat, tmpHistMat;

    float value_ranges[] = {(float)0, (float)MAX_DISP};
    const float* hist_ranges[] = {value_ranges};
    int channels[] = {0};
    int histSize[] = {MAX_DISP};


    struct timespec start, finish;
    double elapsed;

    while(1)
    {
        CYCLE++;

        // === CLEANUP ==
        image = cv::Mat::zeros(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, CV_8U);
        uhist = cv::Mat::zeros(IMAGE_HEIGHT, MAX_DISP, CV_32F);
        vhist = cv::Mat::zeros(MAX_DISP, IMAGE_WIDTH, CV_32F);

        // === CREATE FAKE DISPARITY WITH OBJECTS ===
        for(int i = 0; i < IMAGE_HEIGHT; i++)
            image.row(i) = ((float)i / IMAGE_HEIGHT * MAX_DISP);

        draw_object(image, 200, 500);
        draw_object(image, 525 + CYCLE%100, 275);
        draw_object(image, 500, 300 + CYCLE%100);

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

        // === CALCULATE V-HIST ===
        for(int i = 0; i < IMAGE_HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            tmpImageMat = image.row(i);
            vhist.row(i).copyTo(tmpHistMat);

            cv::calcHist(&tmpImageMat, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), tmpHistMat, 1, histSize, hist_ranges, true, false);

            vhist.row(i) = tmpHistMat.t() / (float) IMAGE_HEIGHT;
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
        elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
        elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) * 1e-9;
        cout << "V-HIST-TIME: " << elapsed << endl;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

        // === CALCULATE U-HIST ===
        for(int i = 0; i < IMAGE_WIDTH; i++)
        {
            tmpImageMat = image.col(i);
            uhist.col(i).copyTo(tmpHistMat);

            cv::calcHist(&tmpImageMat, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), tmpHistMat, 1, histSize, hist_ranges, true, false);

            uhist.col(i) = tmpHistMat / (float) IMAGE_WIDTH;
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
        elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
        elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) * 1e-9;
        cout << "U-HIST-TIME: " << elapsed << endl;

        // === PREPARE AND SHOW RESULTS ===

        uhist.convertTo(uhist, CV_8U, 255);
        cv::applyColorMap(uhist, uhist, cv::COLORMAP_JET);

        vhist.convertTo(vhist, CV_8U, 255);
        cv::applyColorMap(vhist, vhist, cv::COLORMAP_JET);

        cv::imshow("image", image);
        cv::imshow("uhist", uhist);
        cv::imshow("vhist", vhist);



        if ((cv::waitKey(1)&255) == 'q')
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

[image]
Figure 1: v-disparity

[image: fake disparity matrix]
Figure 2: Fake disparity matrix

[image]
Figure 3: u-disparity

---

1. edit:

   - correct name for u- and v-disparity and separate time measurement in c++ example
   - small typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i had the possibility to reinvestigate the problem. Remembering the OpenCV basics ([1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html)) for the `Mat`-structure and the fact that only one calculation takes a huge amount of time, i had the solution.

In OpenCV, each row of an image could be reached by a row-pointer. For iterating columns (done in u-disparity calculation) i suspect, that OpenCV needs to resolve every row-pointer + column-offset for building the histogram.

Changing the Code in a way, that OpenCV is able to use row-pointer, solves the problem for me.

```
            | old code [s] | changed [s]
------------+--------------+-------------
V-HIST-TIME | 0.00351909   | 0.00334152
U-HIST-TIME | 0.600039     | 0.00449285
```

So for the u-hist-loop i transpose the image and reverse the operation after the loop. The line wise access for calculation could now be done via the row-pointer.

Changed Codelines:

```
        // === CALCULATE U-HIST ===
        image = image.t();
        for(int i = 0; i < IMAGE_WIDTH; i++)
        {
            tmpImageMat = image.row(i);
            uhist.col(i).copyTo(tmpHistMat);

            cv::calcHist(&tmpImageMat, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), tmpHistMat, 1, histSize, hist_ranges, true, false);

            uhist.col(i) = tmpHistMat / (float) IMAGE_WIDTH;
        }
        image = image.t();
```

---

Finally my second question takes effect, the runtime-issue belongs not to the loop. A time less than 5 ms is (for now) fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice code and very illustrative. It helped me understand u-disparity.  However, your C/C++ code is broken. I fixed him with this code:

```
cv::Mat uhist = cv::Mat::zeros(MAX_DISP, IMAGE_WIDTH, CV_32F);
cv::Mat vhist = cv::Mat::zeros(IMAGE_WIDTH, MAX_DISP, CV_32F);
```